# How to guarantee that std::cout always uses n width

Tags: c++, iomanip

I have output that looks like this:

```
BTC-USDT              [FTX] 20460.91 20470.09
BTC-USDT              [BINANCE_US] 20457.34 20467.28 
BTC-USDT              [BINANCE_US] 20457.50 20467.28
```

I would like it to look like this:

```
BTC-USDT  [       FTX] 20460.91 20470.09 
BTC-USDT  [BINANCE_US] 20457.34 20467.28
BTC-USDT  [BINANCE_US] 20457.50 20467.28
```

I think I am close with this code, but I am confused by `setw()`

```
std::cout << pair << std::setfill(' ') << std::setw(15) << " [" << exch << "] " << fixed << setprecision(2) <<  bid << " " << ask << std::endl;
```

Comment: The fill and width settings are being applied to the `" ["`, not the `exch`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a given value to have certain output characteristics, like width, alignment, etc, you need to apply the appropriate I/O manipulator(s) *before* you output the value, not *after*.

In your example, you want `pair` to be left-aligned with a width of 9, and `exch` to be right-aligned with a with of 10, so apply `std::setw` and `std::left`/`std::right` accordingly, eg:

```cpp
std::cout << std::setfill(' ')
          << std::setw(9) << std::left << pair
          << " [" << std::setw(10) << std::right << exch << "] "
          << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << bid << ' ' << ask
          << std::endl;
```

Output:

```
BTC-USDT  [       FTX] 20460.91 20470.09
BTC-USDT  [BINANCE_US] 20457.34 20467.28
BTC-USDT  [BINANCE_US] 20457.50 20467.28
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/v3qEFg)

Answer (score 3):

As noted in comments, iomanip settings need to be applied before the item they are meant to apply to.

Filling in values for the missing variables from your example:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::cout << "Foo " << "[" 
            << std::setfill(' ') << std::setw(15)
            << "Bar" << "] " 
            << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) <<  20.897
            << " " << 1.4566 << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Foo [            Bar] 20.90 1.46
```